# How to set discount amount when create order programmically

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4

I have created an order pragmatically and invoiced it forcefully to complete order when I check order under sales->order it shows the order completed but discount column always with zero amount.How to show given discount on products in invoiced.please help

below is my code working fine but need to add discount price.

```
  $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setStore($store);
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
    $quote->setStore($store);
    $hasCustomer=$_REQUEST['hasCustomer'];
    if($hasCustomer=='existing'){
        $customer->loadByEmail($_REQUEST['customerEmail']);
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress());
       $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress());
    }
    else
    {
         $quote->setCustomerEmail($_REQUEST['customerEmail']);
         $addressData = array(
        'firstname' => ' ',
        'lastname' => ' ',
        'street' => ' ',
        'city' => 'NULL',
        'postcode' => 'NULL',
        'telephone' => '123456',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region_id' => 12,  );
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);
    }
    $productIds=array();
    $products=$_REQUEST['productIds'];
    $products=str_replace(array( '[', ']' ), '',$products);
    $productIds=explode(',',$products);
    $quant=$_REQUEST['quantity'];
    $quant=str_replace(array( '[', ']' ), '',$quant);
    $quantities=explode(',',$quant);
    $salesReport=array_combine($productIds,$quantities);
    foreach($salesReport as $ids=>$qty)
    {
        $product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ids); /* HTC Touch Diamond */
        $buyInfo1 = array('qty' => $qty);
        $quoteItem=$quote->addProduct($product1, new Varien_Object($buyInfo1));
     }
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
        ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
    $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
    $quote->setDiscountAmount('2');// I have doubt here
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $order = $service->getOrder();


    $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
    $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
    $invoice->register();
    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
             ->addObject($invoice)
            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
    $transaction->save();
    $order->setData('state',"complete");
    $order->setStatus("complete");
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order marked as complete automatically.', false);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
    $id=$order->getId();
```

In short I want to show orders with discount column price value that I have to give with request method.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way is generate a discount with coupon code like "progr_code" (to identify it is programatically set) and replace

```
$quote->setDiscountAmount('2');// I have doubt here
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

with

```
$quote->setCouponCode("progr_code")
->collectTotals()
->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround if you don't need to have the "Discount" row in the order's totals, but just to have the "Grand total" to take the discount into account, you can divide the discount by the number for items and then use the result in the product's special_price. For instance:

```
$numberOfItems = 0;
$totalDiscount = 2;
foreach($salesReport as $ids=>$qty) {
  $numberOfItems += $qty;
}
$discountByItem = $totalDiscount / $numberOfItems
```

then when adding the items to the quote you can do:

```
$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ids);
$product1['special_price'] = $product1['price'] - $discountByItem;
$buyInfo1 = array('qty' => $qty);
$quoteItem=$quote->addProduct($product1, new Varien_Object($buyInfo1));
```