# Dynamically change discount cost in cart

Tags: cart, discount

In my magento store how can i go about changing the discount total in my shopping cart dynamically?

I'm able to access and get the current discount with this code:

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$totals =  $quote->getTotals(); 
$discount = $totals["discount"]->getValue();
?>
```

I have a button in my shopping cart that when pressed should add an extra £5 onto the discount value, updating the total cost etc at the same time.

Comment: Here is similiar question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/how-to-set-discount-amount-when-create-order-programmically

Answer (score 2):

First of all create module control file Module name as  Amit_Custommodule.xml at `app/etc/modules/`

1. config.xml is `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/`

code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
            </custommodule>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custommodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                    <frontName>custommodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </custommodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

3.`Amit>Custommodule>controllers>IndexController`

code is

```
<?php

    class Amit_Custommodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

        public function applyAction(){

     $quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

           $quoteid=$quote->getId();
           $discountAmount=10;
        if($quoteid) {



            if($discountAmount>0) {
      $total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
       $quote->setSubtotal(0);
       $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

       $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
       $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

       $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
       $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);


       $canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual()? ('billing') : ('shipping'); 
       foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {

       $address->setSubtotal(0);
                $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                $address->collectTotals();

                $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                    (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );
                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                    (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );

                $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

       $quote ->save(); 

          $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->save(); 


        if($address->getAddressType()==$canAddItems) {
        //echo $address->setDiscountAmount; exit;
         $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
         if($address->getDiscountDescription()){
         $address->setDiscountAmount(-($address->getDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
         $address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription().', Custom Discount');
         $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
         }else {
         $address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
         $address->setDiscountDescription('Custom Discount');
         $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
         }
         $address->save();
        }//end: if
       } //end: foreach
       //echo $quote->getGrandTotal();

      foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
                     //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
                     $rat=$item->getPriceInclTax()/$total;
                     $ratdisc=$discountAmount*$rat;
                     $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
                     $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();

                   }


                }

        }

     $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');

        }
        public function calcelAction(){

     $quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

           $quoteid=$quote->getId();
           $discountAmount=0;
        if($quoteid) {



            if($discountAmount>0) {
      $total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
       $quote->setSubtotal(0);
       $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

       $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
       $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

       $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
       $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);


       $canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual()? ('billing') : ('shipping'); 
       foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {

       $address->setSubtotal(0);
                $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                $address->collectTotals();

                $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                    (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );
                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                    (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );

                $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

       $quote ->save(); 

          $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
          ->save(); 


        if($address->getAddressType()==$canAddItems) {
        //echo $address->setDiscountAmount; exit;
         $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
         $address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
         if($address->getDiscountDescription()){
         $address->setDiscountAmount(-($address->getDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
         $address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription().', Custom Discount');
         $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
         }else {
         $address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
         $address->setDiscountDescription('Custom Discount');
         $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
         }
         $address->save();
        }//end: if
       } //end: foreach
       //echo $quote->getGrandTotal();

      foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
                     //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
                     $rat=$item->getPriceInclTax()/$total;
                     $ratdisc=$discountAmount*$rat;
                     $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
                     $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();

                   }


                }

        }

     $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');

        }
    }
```

For apply discount for use below url `custommodule/index/apply`

and cancel this discount `custommodule/index/cancel`

Comment: Can I use the above concept in removing tax also?